# When using ex. in a sentence to provide an example, should the E be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

For example:  "To group your information, drill down on your columns. (ex. In a date field........)

Comment: I've never seen it capitalized, and I can't think of a good argument for why it should be. That said, in my experience *e.g.* is **much** more widely employed than *ex.* (even though Latin died with Vatican II).

Comment: Most British readers would interpret 'ex' as 'excluding', not 'example'.  An example is introduced by 'e.g.'.

Comment: No, and the `x` should be written as `.g.`

Comment: It's not an abbreviation for a proper noun. So you capitalize it using ordinary rules: If it's at the beginning of a sentence, you capitalize it, otherwise it's lowercase.